# How to insert an element at specific position after removing it?

Tags: jquery

this is the html structure when there is an error for input with `id engraving_txt_1` but that error only comes while validating the form, and that `engraving_txt_1 input field` is inserting if user select yes from a dropdown and will be removed when user select no in that dropdown. I am inserting with this code `$(engraving_li).insertBefore("#divcount_1");` , it inserts correctly at the position where I want but when error id `engraving_txt_1-error` becomes visible it messed up. How can I insert it correctly whether there is error or not?

```
<div id="li_engraving_txt_1" class="row" style="display: block;">
 <span class="type1 form-group col-md-2"><span class="left-label"><span id="red">*</span>Engraving Text:</span>
   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   <label id="engraving_txt_1-error" class="fieldError" for="engraving_txt_1">This field is required.</label>
   <label style="margin-left:25%;" id="divcount_1"></label>
   <input type="hidden" id="label_1" name="labelCount[]" class="element text form-control" value="">
 </span>
 <span class="type1 form-group col-md-2"><span class="left-label"><span id="red">*</span>Engraving Font:</span>
   <select class="element select form-control" id="engraving_font_1" name="cb_engraving_font[]">
     <option value="Cherokee Font">Cherokee Font</option>
     <option value="Narkism Font">Narkism Font</option>
     <option value="Segoe Script Font">Segoe Script Font</option>
   </select>
 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: On which position do you want it to appear?

Comment: where I have it in the sample code

Comment: '$(engraving_li).insertBefore("#divcount_1");' you want to insert engraving_li - right? i can't see it in your code

Comment: maybe update your code and just put a XXXXXXXXXX at the position you want your element to appear - that would be awesome/easy...

Comment: here we go - nice

Comment: OK updated now !

Comment: Why not just change the style for the display property in JavaScript for the label you want to show?

Comment: sorry my first version was wrong - made an update. run the snippet and you will see its right... if not leave a comment

Comment: You are welcome... BTW: Your code is not valid! The `id` attribute is meant to be unique. You have two times `id="red"` in your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must be as specific as possible to not target the unwanted DOM-elements.

```js
$('#li_engraving_txt_1')
    .find('.type1.form-group.col-md-2')
        .first()
            .find('.left-label')
                .after('.......HIT........')
```

```html
<div id="li_engraving_txt_1" class="row" style="display: block;">
 <span class="type1 form-group col-md-2"><span class="left-label"><span id="red">*</span>Engraving Text:</span>
   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   <label id="engraving_txt_1-error" class="fieldError" for="engraving_txt_1">This field is required.</label>
   <label style="margin-left:25%;" id="divcount_1"></label>
   <input type="hidden" id="label_1" name="labelCount[]" class="element text form-control" value="">
 </span>
 <span class="type1 form-group col-md-2"><span class="left-label"><span id="red">*</span>Engraving Font:</span>
   <select class="element select form-control" id="engraving_font_1" name="cb_engraving_font[]">
     <option value="Cherokee Font">Cherokee Font</option>
     <option value="Narkism Font">Narkism Font</option>
     <option value="Segoe Script Font">Segoe Script Font</option>
   </select>
 </span>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```